# Recovering a separate default branch after merging it with a sub branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, codeplex

I think I have messed up my Mercurial repository branching by merging the sub branch into a default one:

[image: Merged mercurial branch]

Have I merged them, according to the screen shot?
If so, how can I have my TimeSpan localization branch separated again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not merged, the *default* branch just not showing up anything (since you're currenly not working on it, and I don't see any merge commits anywhere as well). If you update to your default branch, your "*Time Span Localization*" branch should become clearily visible in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up to Alex and second part of answer:

No, you have nothing merged, you just have none changesets after 0 in default branch.

1+ is work in your separate branch only. In order to get two (visible in workbench) heads of two branches you can update to default, edit, commit and see **live** default branch. Results of `hg branches` and `hg heads` will show real state of your repo any time